# How to compare firebase registered users with existing firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've implemented firebase authentication where users can register with email id and password now in my app i'm providing custom plans to a user i.e when a user selects a plan from a list of plans that select plan should be assigned to the current logged in user and whenever user logs back in only that plan should be visible to him how can i do that?

Comment: Please put your code which you tried

Comment: @RuchitPatel, did my answer work for you?

Comment: @Pradyuman DIxit, Yeah it did help me figure out the logic however i've changed my code a little bit and soon my task will be accomplished

Comment: @RuchitPatel if my answer helped you, consider marking it as correct and upvoting it. I'd appreciate that. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make separate nodes for each of your users. What I mean is when they sign up, you can store them in a node named, `common_users` and when they select a plan, you can take their name out from the `common_users` and store them in a new node with name `planName_users`.

I'm not giving the code for authenticated users being stored in your database under node like `common_users` here, as you must have implemented that already.

When a user from the app, selects a plan, you may use a code like this to take him out of the list of `common_users`.

```java
FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

String curUid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("common_users");
 ref.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(curUid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                       //remove this user
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

Now you can just put him in your new node like `planeName_users` and then use that to further determine how your user should see things in the app.